# group some row in resilt table

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I need get a group some row select from result table. I've written select but have error message ORA-00913. How to write a correct select ?I have a 
result table:

```
DROP TABLE MONEY_ACTIVITY;
CREATE TABLE MONEY_ACTIVITY (
       ID                   NUMBER(15) NOT NULL,
       DOCUMENT_NUMBER      VARCHAR2(13) NULL,
       ID_CUSTOMER          NUMBER NULL,
       BASE_AMOUNT          NUMBER(5,2) NULL
);
```

and insert:

```
INSERT INTO MONEY_ACTIVITY  VALUES (1, 'input_saldo', 111222, 300);
INSERT INTO MONEY_ACTIVITY  VALUES (2, 'input_saldo', 222333, 600);
INSERT INTO MONEY_ACTIVITY  VALUES (3, 'ouput_saldo', 333444, 400);
INSERT INTO MONEY_ACTIVITY  VALUES (4, 'ouput_saldo', 444555, 600);
INSERT INTO MONEY_ACTIVITY  VALUES (5, 'TN0001', 444555, 600);
INSERT INTO MONEY_ACTIVITY  VALUES (6, 'TN0002', 444555, 700);
INSERT INTO MONEY_ACTIVITY  VALUES (7, 'TN0003', 333444, 600);
INSERT INTO MONEY_ACTIVITY  VALUES (8, 'TN0004', 333444, 700);
INSERT INTO MONEY_ACTIVITY  VALUES (9, 'TN0005', 111444, 600);
INSERT INTO MONEY_ACTIVITY  VALUES (10, 'TN0006', 222444, 700);
```

and I need to get result table:

```
input_saldo 900
ouput_saldo 1000
TN0001  600
TN0002  700
TN0003  600
TN0004  700
TN0005  600
TN0006  700
```

I'm trying:

```
select 
case when DOCUMENT_NUMBER = 'input_saldo' then  (select DOCUMENT_NUMBER, SUM(BASE_AMOUNT)
                                                 from MONEY_ACTIVITY   
                                                 where DOCUMENT_NUMBER = 'input_saldo'
                                                 group by DOCUMENT_NUMBER) end case,   
case when DOCUMENT_NUMBER = 'ouput_saldo' then  (select DOCUMENT_NUMBER, SUM(BASE_AMOUNT)
                                                 from MONEY_ACTIVITY   
                                                 where DOCUMENT_NUMBER = 'ouput_saldo'
                                                 group by DOCUMENT_NUMBER) end case,                                                 
DOCUMENT_NUMBER, 
BASE_AMOUNT 
from MONEY_ACTIVITY
where DOCUMENT_NUMBER NOT IN ('input_saldo', 'output_saldo');
```

but  ora-00913 too many values

How to write correct "select" ?

Sorry, There is some new conditions. The table can contain rows with the same Document_number and different ID_customer. This rows must not to add up summarize.

Example:

1   input_saldo 111222  300
2   input_saldo 222333  600
4   ouput_saldo 444555  600
3   ouput_saldo 333444  400
11  TN0001  333444  600    --!!!!!!!
5   TN0001  444555  600    --!!!!!!!
6   TN0002  444555  700
......

And I try execute:

```
SELECT DOCUMENT_NUMBER, ID_CUSTOMER, SUM(BASE_AMOUNT)
FROM MONEY_ACTIVITY
GROUP BY DOCUMENT_NUMBER, ID_CUSTOMER;
```

Return result is:

DOCUMENT_NUMBER ID_CUSTOMER SUM(BASE_AMOUNT)

```
input_saldo 222333  600
input_saldo 111222  300
ouput_saldo 333444  400
ouput_saldo 444555  600
TN0001  444555  600
TN0001  333444  600
TN0002  444555  700
TN0003  333444  600
TN0004  333444  700
TN0005  111444  600
TN0006  222444  700
```

But I need:

```
input_saldo 111222  900
ouput_saldo 444555  1000
TN0001  444555  600
TN0001  333444  600
TN0002  444555  700
TN0003  333444  600
TN0004  333444  700
TN0005  111444  600
TN0006  222444  700
```

Comment: Skip the sub-queries, do JOINs instead.

Comment: 1 input_saldo 111222 300
2 input_saldo 222333 600
4 ouput_saldo 444555 600
3 ouput_saldo 333444 400
11 TN0001 333444 600    --!!!!!!!
5 TN0001 444555 600    --!!!!!!!
6 TN0002 444555 700
......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 
    case when DOCUMENT_NUMBER in ('input_saldo', 'ouput_saldo')  then DOCUMENT_NUMBER else DOCUMENT_NUMBER_1 end DOCUMENT_NUMBER,
    case when DOCUMENT_NUMBER in ('input_saldo', 'ouput_saldo')  then BASE_AMOUNT else BASE_AMOUNT_1 end BASE_AMOUNT,
    case when DOCUMENT_NUMBER in ('input_saldo', 'ouput_saldo') then null else ID_CUSTOMER_1 end ID_CUSTOMER
from 
    (select DOCUMENT_NUMBER, 
        sum(BASE_AMOUNT) BASE_AMOUNT,  
        DOCUMENT_NUMBER_1, 
        BASE_AMOUNT_1, 
        ID_CUSTOMER_1
    from 
        (select 
            case when DOCUMENT_NUMBER in ('input_saldo', 'ouput_saldo')  then DOCUMENT_NUMBER else null end DOCUMENT_NUMBER,
            case when DOCUMENT_NUMBER in ('input_saldo', 'ouput_saldo') then BASE_AMOUNT else null end BASE_AMOUNT,
            case when DOCUMENT_NUMBER in ('input_saldo', 'ouput_saldo') then  null else ID end ID_1,
            case when DOCUMENT_NUMBER in ('input_saldo', 'ouput_saldo') then null else DOCUMENT_NUMBER end DOCUMENT_NUMBER_1,
            case when DOCUMENT_NUMBER in ('input_saldo', 'ouput_saldo') then  null else BASE_AMOUNT end BASE_AMOUNT_1,
            case when DOCUMENT_NUMBER in ('input_saldo', 'ouput_saldo') then  null else ID_CUSTOMER end ID_CUSTOMER_1          
        from MONEY_ACTIVITY)
    group by DOCUMENT_NUMBER, DOCUMENT_NUMBER_1, BASE_AMOUNT_1, ID_CUSTOMER_1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use GROUP BY-

```
SELECT DOCUMENT_NUMBER ,SUM(BASE_AMOUNT)
FROM MONEY_ACTIVITY  
GROUP BY DOCUMENT_NUMBER
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply an aggregating function, for example:

```
SELECT DOCUMENT_NUMBER, SUM(BASE_AMOUNT)
FROM MONEY_ACTIVITY
GROUP BY DOCUMENT_NUMBER
ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that error is becouse your subquery should return one value (sum(BASE_AMOUNT)).
Remove column DOCUMENT_NUMBER from subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Not by the merits of the logic of the query limit myself only to the error reported .. subqueries return two columns while the result should contain only one

```
select 
case when DOCUMENT_NUMBER = 'input_saldo' then  (select  SUM(BASE_AMOUNT)
                                                 from MONEY_ACTIVITY   
                                                 where DOCUMENT_NUMBER = 'input_saldo'
                                                 group by DOCUMENT_NUMBER) end case,   
case when DOCUMENT_NUMBER = 'ouput_saldo' then  (select  SUM(BASE_AMOUNT)
                                                 from MONEY_ACTIVITY   
                                                 where DOCUMENT_NUMBER = 'ouput_saldo'
                                                 group by DOCUMENT_NUMBER) end case,                                                 
DOCUMENT_NUMBER, 
BASE_AMOUNT 
from MONEY_ACTIVITY
where DOCUMENT_NUMBER NOT IN ('input_saldo', 'output_saldo');
```

Answer (score 0):

From your data sample, a simple aggregation does the work:

```
select DOCUMENT_NUMBER, sum(BASE_AMOUNT)
from MONEY_ACTIVITY
group by DOCUMENT_NUMBER
```

If you need a more complex logic, please edit your question to better explain your need

Answer (score 0):

Why not use simple query ?

```
SELECT DOCUMENT_NUMBER,SUM(BASE_AMOUNT)
FROM MONEY_ACTIVITY
GROUP BY DOCUMENT_NUMBER
```

Comment: Thank you JaydipJ !

Answer (score 0):

You have a subquery to populate a scalar value and the subquery is returning two values.
As per MarinC answer above you could just remove DOCUMENT_NUMBER from the subqueries.

Your query also looks wrong as you appear to have mis-spelled 'output_saldo' and you are specifically excluding the two '...saldo' values so they will never appear in the result set anyway.

This does what you seem to be asking without using the sub-queries;

```
SELECT document_number, SUM(base_amount) 
  FROM money_activity
GROUP BY document_number
ORDER BY document_number desc
```